# Enabling CORS in a Cloud 9 service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, c9.io, rack-cors

I'm using a C9 AWS instance to run an API REST written in ruby on rails, and i'm consuming the resources from an Ionic App with simple http calls.
When i make a http request from the ionic app, the server response with this message: 

`Failed to load https://the_server.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/resource: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

**How can I enable the CORS in the Cloud 9 instance ?**

I have already enable the CORS in rails with the **rack-cors** gem

Comment: AFAIK, there seems to be an option to set the instance to public instead of private...if you set it to public it should give you cors access

Comment: Do you know how to change that ?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `https://the_server.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/resource` is being handled by a proxy. To allow CORS, you need to call the server directly. You can do that 
 by connecting to the server IP address, and opening the correct ports. It's described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html?icmpid=docs_ac9_ide#app-preview-share